# Change back dataframe to original form in R

Tags: r

```
> dput(Data)
structure(list(Date = c("2020-02-12", "2020-02-12", "2020-02-12", 
"2020-02-12", "2020-02-12", "2020-02-12", "2020-02-12", "2020-02-12", 
"2020-02-12", "2020-02-12", "2020-02-12", "2020-02-12"), Day = c("Wednesday", 
"Wednesday", "Wednesday", "Wednesday", "Wednesday", "Wednesday", 
"Wednesday", "Wednesday", "Wednesday", "Wednesday", "Wednesday", 
"Wednesday"), Time.Slots = c("9AM-10AM", "10AM-11AM", "11AM-12PM", 
"12PM-1PM", "1PM-2PM", "2PM-3PM", "3PM-4PM", "4PM-5PM", "5PM-6PM", 
"6PM-7PM", "7PM-8PM", "8PM-9PM"), Two.Wheelers = c(67L, 54L, 
30L, 51L, 49L, 26L, 34L, 32L, 39L, 31L, 40L, 26L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-12L), class = "data.frame")
> Data 
         Date       Day Time.Slots Two.Wheelers
1  2020-02-12 Wednesday   9AM-10AM           67
2  2020-02-12 Wednesday  10AM-11AM           54
3  2020-02-12 Wednesday  11AM-12PM           30
4  2020-02-12 Wednesday   12PM-1PM           51
5  2020-02-12 Wednesday    1PM-2PM           49
6  2020-02-12 Wednesday    2PM-3PM           26
7  2020-02-12 Wednesday    3PM-4PM           34
8  2020-02-12 Wednesday    4PM-5PM           32
9  2020-02-12 Wednesday    5PM-6PM           39
10 2020-02-12 Wednesday    6PM-7PM           31
11 2020-02-12 Wednesday    7PM-8PM           40
12 2020-02-12 Wednesday    8PM-9PM           26
```

After arrange and finding ranks I get this.

```
Data <- Data %>% 
          filter(Day=="Wednesday") %>% 
          arrange(Two.Wheelers) %>%
          select(Date,Day,Time.Slots,Two.Wheelers) %>%
          mutate(count=seq(1,12))
Data
         Date       Day Time.Slots Two.Wheelers count
1  2020-02-12 Wednesday    2PM-3PM           26     1
2  2020-02-12 Wednesday    8PM-9PM           26     2
3  2020-02-12 Wednesday  11AM-12PM           30     3
4  2020-02-12 Wednesday    6PM-7PM           31     4
5  2020-02-12 Wednesday    4PM-5PM           32     5
6  2020-02-12 Wednesday    3PM-4PM           34     6
7  2020-02-12 Wednesday    5PM-6PM           39     7
8  2020-02-12 Wednesday    7PM-8PM           40     8
9  2020-02-12 Wednesday    1PM-2PM           49     9
10 2020-02-12 Wednesday   12PM-1PM           51    10
11 2020-02-12 Wednesday  10AM-11AM           54    11
12 2020-02-12 Wednesday   9AM-10AM           67    12
```

How do I revert it back to its original form.From original form I meant is time slots shouldnt get changed first value of time slot should be 9AM - 10 AM and last value of time slots should be 8pm-9pm My time slots are changed now. I just wanted to find ranks but this has altered my dataframe.

Comment: What do you mean with "revert it back to ist original form"? Getting rid of the count column or the row order?

Comment: Time slots should remain in order @deschen starting form 9am

Comment: I would just create the count sequence in your original data frame and then arrange by that column again.

Comment: but lowest two wheeler count should get rank 1 @deschen

Comment: What is your expected output? On what basis do you want to assign ranks? If it is based on time and your data is already ordered isn't it just `Data %>%  mutate(count = row_number())` ?

Comment: @RonakShah lowest value of two-wheeler is rank 1 but time slots shouldnt change they should start from 9AM end last should be of time slot 8PM

Comment: `Data %>% mutate(count = dense_rank(Two.Wheelers))` ?